# convert a string into value in R

Tags: r

Take for example:

```
s <- c("1y1","2y1","1.5y2","1.8y2")
```

y1 and y2 means to multiply 2 and 1.8.

```
1y1 = 1*2=2    
1.5y2 = 1.5*1.8 = 2.7
```

So, the result would be `c(2,4,2.7,3.24)`.
How can I simply get it?

I can do it by `c(1,2.5,3,2.7)*c(2,2,1.8,1.8)`, but it is not elegant, if the string is very long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gsub` to replace y1 and y2 by their respective numeric values then one can use the classical eval(parse(..)) to evaluate the resulted numeric expressions.

```
s <- c("1y1","2y1","1.5y2","1.8y2")

s <- gsub('y1','*2',s)
s <-gsub('y2','*1.8',s)

sapply(s,function(x)eval(parse(text=x)))
1*2     2*2 1.5*1.8 1.8*1.8 
2.00    4.00    2.70    3.24
```

**EDIT** more elegant option using `gsubfn`, and its flexible function substitution version.

```
> library(gsubfn)
> sub.f <- function(x,y) as.numeric(x) * ifelse(y == 1, 2, 1. 8)
> as.numeric(gsubfn('(.*)y(.*)', sub.f, s))
 [1] 2.00 4.00 2.70 3.24
```

we split, each expression into 2 components x and y and use them (once coerced to numeric) to compute manually the expression.

Alternately, this one liner:

```
> strapply(s, '(.*)y(.*)', ~ as.numeric(x) * ifelse(y == 1, 2, 1.8), simplify = TRUE)
[1] 2.00 4.00 2.70 3.24
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
s = sub(pattern="y", replacement="*y", x=s)
```

`sub` will replace all the ocurrences of `y` with `*y`, so the expression is syntactically correct to R. However, it's not really an expression but a character vector. Take notice `sub` will replace only the first ocurrence of `y`. If there are more than one "`y`" per string, you have to use `gsub` instead. For more information see `?sub`.

```
y1 = 2
y2 = 1.8

s = parse(text=s) # parse will convert s to a R expression
s.num = sapply(s, eval) # and this will evaluate the expression to give the results

[1] 2.00 4.00 2.70 3.24
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea:

```
s <- c("1y1", "2y1", "1.5y2", "1.8y2")
s2 <- as.numeric(sub("y[0-9]", "", s))

mult <- rep(NA, len = length(s))
mult[grep("y1", s)] <- 2
mult[grep("y2", s)] <- 1.8

s2 * mult
#[1] 2.00 4.00 2.70 3.24
```

On a larger scale:

```
S = sample(s, 1e4, T)
f1 = function() {
      S <- gsub('y1','*2',S)
      S <-gsub('y2','*1.8',S)
      sapply(S,function(x)eval(parse(text=x)))
     }
f2 = function() {
        S = sub(pattern="y", replacement="*y", x=S)
        S = parse(text=S) 
        S.num = sapply(S, eval)
        S.num
     } ; y1 = 2 ; y2 = 1.8
f3 = function() {
      s2 <- as.numeric(sub("y[0-9]", "", S))
      mult <- rep(NA, len = length(S))
      mult[grep("y1", S)] <- 2
      mult[grep("y2", S)] <- 1.8
      s2 * mult
     }
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr        min         lq    median         uq        max neval
# f1() 1940.63876 2037.03500 2064.4605 2072.98875 2101.73358    10
# f2()   93.43298   98.69724  115.8716  125.07774  153.43385    10
# f3()   12.91724   13.01781   13.1805   13.30283   17.94973    10
sum(f1() != f2())
#[1] 0
sum(f2() != f3())
#[1] 0
```